# Why do CMB polarisation measurements focus on the tensor-to-scalar ratio, r instead of the amplitude and spectral index?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

Someone asked me this question and I realised I don't have a good answer. I also can't seem to find anything in the literature that explains why the tensor-to-scalar ratio, $r$ is so much more commonly used than the amplitude, $A_t$ and spectral index $n_t$.

The best explanation I could think of is that it reduces two parameters, $A_T$ and $n_t$ to one, but $r(A_t,A_s,n_t,n_s)$ (as well as k) due to it being defined as the ratio of the tensor-to-scalar power spectra.

Does this have a more observational explanation (e.g. more simply dependent on Stokes parameters)? If you have measured the two power from two separate CMB maps is it not an extra step to then calculate $r$?

Comment: This paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.6530v3.pdf (p2) suggests that $r$ is a sensible parameter until we find it to be non-zero...

Comment: My guess (and I make this from having observed the phenomenon first hand) is that cosmologists have a preference towards making things as complicated to read and understand as possible and then act as though it couldn't have been any other way. I can't say for sure that this is what happened, but it wouldn't be the first time my peers have made things far more obfuscated than necessary. I understand why they do it. If you simplify for others to understand, it's hard to get your work published; it starts looking too trivial